Регулярные выражения в PostgreSql
Есть такая строка в столбце body (кроме этого в нем еще много всего лежит в таком же виде):
"incidentUuid":"319afdab-9be7-4fb1-a344-53414a29846a"
Требуется написать код на PostgreSql используя регулярное выражение, чтоб достать id инцидента из этой строки - 319afdab-9be7-4fb1-a344-53414a29846a
(id имеет разные цифры и буквы и они находятся в разных позициях между дефисами, но его структура всегда одна)
Моя попытка решить это вот так не дает результатов:
regexp_replace( regexp_matches(body::text,'"incidentUuid":"\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.','g')::text ,'(})|({|,)','','g') as Inc_id

Так там же джсон в столбце хранится.

Пф... взять 36 символов строго после "incidentUuid":"  - и вот зачем тут регулярка? я уж не говорю о том, что при фиксированном JSON-пути к нужному значению задача вообще тривиальна.

Добрый день. Так не получится, потому что в body еще около 10 разных идентификаторов кроме этого, и все они в таком виде

в body еще около 10 разных идентификаторов кроме этого, и все они в таком виде Процессу извлечения данных из JSON это совершенно не мешает.

Получилось с помощью вот такого кода:
regexp_matches(body:text, '"incidentUuid":"([0-9a-fA-F-]+)"') AS incident_id

Спасибо за помощь.
